# Converting .las files to LAS datasets using ModelBuilder iterator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, lidar, iterator, las, lasd

I have 1500 individual LAS files and I need to move them to separate LAS datasets (so 1500 LAS datasets).

I've used iterator (iterate files) in ModelBuilder and it creates 1500 individual LAS datasets with correct individual names but they all have points just from first .als file.

There is nothing wrong with .las files since I can open them in Global Mapper.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solved. Apparently this only works when some prefix is added to lasd name. Example: D_%Name%.lasd